# After uploading to server images not showing in web browser in html

Tags: html

Hi Localhost working fine after uploading all the files to server it's not showing images in web browser in html and layout design also got changes.I want exactly localhost how it's working same I want.
can any one please help me
**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/grid.css" type="text/css" media="screen">   
    <script src="js/jquery-1.6.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/cufon-yui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/cufon-replace.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/Kozuka_Gothic_Pro_OpenType_300.font.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/Kozuka_Gothic_Pro_OpenType_500.font.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="js/FF-cash.js" type="text/javascript"></script>      
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tms-0.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tms_presets.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jcarousellite_1.0.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            $('.carousel .jCarouselLite').jCarouselLite({ 
                btnNext: '.carousel .next',
                btnPrev: '.carousel .prev',
                speed: 600,
                easing: 'easeOutQuart',
                vertical: false,
                circular: false,
                visible: 4,
                start: 0,
                scroll: 1
            }); 
        }); 
    </script>
    <!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <div style=' clear: both; text-align:center; position: relative;'>
        <a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/products/ie/home?ocid=ie6_countdown_bannercode">
            <img src="http://storage.ie6countdown.com/assets/100/images/banners/warning_bar_0000_us.jpg" border="0" height="42" width="820" alt="You are using an outdated browser. For a faster, safer browsing experience, upgrade for free today." />
        </a>
    </div>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/html5.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body id="page1">
    <!--==============================header=================================-->
    <header>

        <div class="row-bot">
            <div class="row-bot-bg">
                <div class="main">
                    <div class="wrapper p6">
                    <img src="images/logo.png" align="right"/>   


                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <figure class="img-indent2"><img src="images/page1-img1.png" alt=""></figure>
                        <div class="extra-wrap">
                            <strong class="text-1">There is no doubt that education is in the eye of the storm that is sweeping the world's economies,Innovation ,Creativity, Collaborative Leadership,Global Connection, and trans-disciplinary skills are among a few of the major drives of success  today's professional.The only educational institutions are unique position of being able to lead the changes required by the entire education system to accommodate a new kind of thinking for a new kind of world. </strong><br>
                            <strong class="text-1">This makes there technologies readily accessible to you, at easily affordable prices and offers plans that suits academic institutes of all sizes and budgets.</strong>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <!--==============================aside================================-->
    <aside>
        <div class="carousel">

            <div class="carousel-container">
                <h3>Popular Design Projects</h3>
                <div class="jCarouselLite">
                    <ul class="carousel-list">
                        <li>
                            <div class="img-border">
                                <a href="#"><img src="images/page1-img2.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="img-border">
                                <a href="#"><img src="images/page1-img3.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="img-border">
                                <a href="#"><img src="images/page1-img4.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </aside>

    <!--==============================content================================-->
    <section id="content"><div class="ic"></div>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="container_12">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <article class="grid_4">
                        <div class="indent-left">
                            <div style="color:#0000FF">
                            <h3 class="p0">Academic Institutions Benefits:</h3></div>

                            <ul class="list-1" >
                                <li><a href="#">Admission & Financial Aid</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Quick Registration & Scheduling</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Parents Portal/ Student Portal & Teachers Portal</a></li> 
                                <li><a href="#">More Trust From Parents</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Quicker Response Time</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Better Services, at a Lower Cost</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Complete Online Package</a></li>

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                    <article class="grid_4">
                        <div class="indent-left">
                            <div style="color:#0000FF">
                            <h3 class="p1">Top Users:</h3></div>
                            <ul class="list-1">
                                <li><a href="#">Instant Attendance Alerts(SMS,Email)</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Progress Reports And Hall Ticket</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Automatic Backup Technology</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Exam Time Tables And Results</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Online Surveillance System</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Online Fees Payment Facility</a></li>

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                    <article class="grid_4">
                        <div class="indent-left2">
                        <div style="color:#0000FF">
                            <h3 class="p1">We Can Manage Which Helps In The Following:</h3></div>
                            <ul class="list-1">
                                <li><a href="#">Customised And Self Branded Message(SMS,Email & Web)</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">No More Laborious And Time Consuming Paper Work</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Online/Onsite Training Sessions </a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">24x7 Customer Services</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">User Friendly System</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Low Maintenance Cost</a></li>

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </article>


                </div>
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <article class="grid_4">
                        <div class="indent-left">
                        <div style="color:#0000FF">
                            <h3 class="p1">Management:</h3></div>
                            <ul class="list-1">
                                <li><a href="#">Manage Communication flow among stake holders</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Integration of all activities performed in the school</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">To maintain transparency in the system</a></li> 
                                <li><a href="#">To fight stiff competition</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">To take care of pillars of school academic,administrative and finance</a></li>


                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                    <article class="grid_4">
                        <div class="indent-left">
                        <div style="color:#0000FF">
                            <h3 class="p1">Students/parents:</h3></div>
                            <ul class="list-1">
                                <li><a href="#">Every student is not able to get personal attention from teacher</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Students are always overburdened</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Only academic performance is considered while grading</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Lateral thinking, life skills and thinking skills are not measured.</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Online Surveillance System</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Online Fees Payment Facility</a></li>

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                    <article class="grid_4">
                        <div class="indent-left2">
                        <div style="color:#0000FF">
                            <h3 class="p1">Teachers:</h3></div>
                            <ul class="list-1">
                                <li><a href="#">Teachers have to manage large amount of data.</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">There are large numbers of students who are needed to be taken care of </a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Teachers have to deal with the repetitive administrative work.</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">The process of continuous comprehensive evaluation need to be followed.</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Manage time table and proxy scheduling</a></li>


                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </article>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!--==============================footer=================================-->
    <footer>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="aligncenter">
                <p class="p0">Rushda Infotech &copy;2014 School, all rights reserved. </p>
                <a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.templatemonster.com/" target="_blank">Website </a> by rushdainfotech.in
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script type="text/javascript"> Cufon.now(); </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function(){
            $('.slider')._TMS({
                duration:800,
                easing:'easeOutQuad',
                preset:'diagonalExpand',
                slideshow:5000
            })
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show us the **relevant** mark-up (not the entire page) and more importantly the **relevant** code-behind

Comment: images not displaying in the above code

Comment: Don't post html, head sections etc.

Comment: @user3436185 - unless you give us more information, we will not be able to (and most likely not want to) help you.  Telling it "it's not working" means NOTHING.  We know it's not working, otherwise you wouldn't be here.  Help us to help you

Comment: logo.png image not showing

Comment: what ur asking I am not getting

Answer (score 0):

Try to get image path from unloaded images by right click and properties. That will show image actual path. Try to validate that path. Its mostly when you deploy on different servers image path would change.

Comment: It would be like "http://appname/imges/logo.gif". Please change and try image path as "~/images/page1-img2.jpg" or "../images/page1-img2.jpg".

Comment: this image not opening

Comment: Right click on image goto Properties and copy Address and share it here

Comment: can you please tell me

Comment: is this your application URL masterpiecefbh.com or masterpiecefbh.com/ <applicationname> ?